# cs50 pset2 caesar---validating the key

Tags: c, cs50

I'm going through cs50 and I'm stuck on pset2 caesar. I'm taking it step-by-step as instructed and I got past the part about validating the key--making sure the command-line argument is only a number (./caesar 20) and if not (./caesar 20x or ./caesar xyz) to print out Usage: ./caesar key\n. But once I add the next lines to prompt the user for plaintext and then print back the ciphertext it doesnt seem to register the former lines that validate the key. I am aware of Harvard's academic integrity policy so I'm more asking for hints/help/explaination with this. I've posted my code below and any help is greatly appreciated.

```
int main(int argc, string argv[])       
{

        int i = 0;
        if(isalpha(argv[1][i]))
        {
            printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            int key = atoi(argv[1]);
            string text = get_string("plaintext: ");
            printf("ciphertext: ");
            int n = strlen(text);
            for(i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                if(isupper(text[i]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((text[i] - 65) + key) % 26) + 65);
                }
                else if(islower(text[i]))
                {
                    printf("%c", (((text[i] - 97) + key) % 26) + 97);
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("%c", text[i]);
                }
            }
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It just readabillity thing, but use the char literals like `'a'` rather then their ASCII values.

Comment: `printf("Usage: ./caesar key\n"); return 1;` is an anti pattern.  If there was no error, the you should `return 0`.  If there was an error, then an error message should have been written to stderr.  A usage statement is not an error message (countless annoying programs that write 100 lines of usage statement as error message to stderr which are then bypassed by the pager when the user re-runs the program with `| less` appended).  In this case, an invalid character is an error, but a usage statement is the incorrect response.  Specify the error, and write to stderr.

Comment: I am not sure what your problem is, but to debug, assign the cipher calculation  to a variable and inspect the variable with the debugger before printing it.

Comment: I assume `get_string` gets a string and allocates a buffer which it returns?

Comment: Don't hard code values like '65', '97', and '26'.  Pretty sure you want `'A'`, `'a'`, and `'z' - 'a' + 1`.  (An argument could be made that 26 is okay, but you definitely want `'a'` and `'A'` instead of 97 and 65.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rework the input validation.

1. It does not ensure that one argument is supplied at the command line.
2. It is only validating the *first character* of `argv[1]`. Program should test that *every* character of the argument is a digit (see `man isdigit`). `isalpha()` is not a good test. What if user enters `$`?

It is not clear when program doesn't work, but this will not pass check50 based on these defects.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check 2 things in the command-line argument.
1. Check if you have 2 arguments. (This is not checked in your program)
2. Check if it is not an alphabet... Since the second argument is automatically a string (due to string argv[]), you must convert it first to integers. ---- this breeds sub-problems that you must take care of by:
2.A. Check the string one-by-one (per CHARACTER) and all must be an integer. 
2.B. If at least one is a character then return false...

2.A. and 2.B. should be a nested in a separate function that would return a boolean value(T/F), then from that boolean value, enclose those two boolean expressions in the while loop.

2 months late on my answer but since I just finished this problem, I thought maybe someone might be experiencing the same difficulty I had with this so hope someone can read this and help them out. :)